# Where To Find Google Cloud Platform API Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am pretty new to GCP, and are working on a project requiring the DialogFlow API.

The purpose of the project is to get an IVR system to connect to the bot and let users interact with it trough their phone.

I have built a test bot that works fine when I test it in the DialogFlow console, or trough Google Assistant.

However, when I try to access the bot trough the telephony system it fails.

Looking at the API Metrics, I can see which methods that fail, however, I am not sure where to find some detailed information about this. I have a screenshot of the methods that fail below:

[image]

I have tried to look at the Logs, but nothing shows. I have also tried to enable Audit Logging for the DialogFlow API, but nothing shows.

I am not sure where to look for the error message, so if anyone knows where this can be found, I would be grateful.

EDIT:
Based on the answer from Jones, I want to clearify:

I have enabled Audit Logging, and have used the filter he specified, however it shows nothing. I have also made sure that I have the right permissions to view logs.

If I look under "Audited Resource" instead of "Global", I get some logs, but not the ones I am looking for. Picture below:

[image]

Ideally, I would like logs that point to why

```
google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.ConversationProfiles.ListConversationProfiles
```

and

```
google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Conversations.CreateConversation
```

Fails.

Comment: There are a few things confusing about your question, and it may help us if you update it with some more info. You've tagged it `dialogflow-fulfillment`, but this doesn't sound like fulfillment code - can you clarify how you are running this code? Showing the code may help as well. You've indicated that "it fails" - how do you know your code fails?

Comment: Hi Prisoner. I have remove the dialogflow-fulfillment tag. I am working with fulfillment in my project, but it is not relevant to my issue. Sorry for the confusion. I will try and update my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled Audit Logging, you can find the logs in Stackdriver using this filter:

```
resource.type="global"
logName="projects/YOUR_PROJECT/logs/dialogflow_agent"
```

You can also just click on **Open logs** under the **Log interaction to Google Cloud** button on your Dialogflow agent's setting page.

Comment: @Mdan, If my answer is correct and did help you achieve your goal, please remind to mark it as accepted so it can help the community in the future.

Comment: unfortunently it did not work. I have updated my question based on your answer. Thanks for yout input though!